# Submit two forms at once - Safari bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, safari

I am trying to submit two forms at the same time using jQuery and ajax. The idea is to optin the email to a separate mailing list which is why 2 forms are needed.

It works for both Chrome and Firefox but not Safari. When I test in Safari it only submits one of the forms.

If anyone has any suggestions that would be a huge help.

My code looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input id="email-input" type="text" name="email" value="" size="11">
    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter-signup" id="newsletter-signup">
    <input id="submit-btn" type="submit" value="SignUp">
</form>

<form id="mailing-list-form">
    <input type='hidden' name='email' id="hidden-email" value='' size='10'>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$('#email-input').change(function() {
  $('#hidden-email').val($(this).val());
});

$("#submit-btn").click(function() {

  if ($("#newsletter-signup").is(':checked')) {
    submitTwoForms();
  } else {
    //do nothing
  }
});

function submitTwoForms() {
  var dataObject = $('#mailing-list-form').serialize();
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://pacmail.em.marketinghq.net/functions/mailing_list.html",
    data: dataObject,
    type: "GET",
    success: function() {
      $('form').each(function() {
        $(this).submit();
      });
    }
  });
  return false; //to prevent submit
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a missing closing parenthesis after the `#submit-btn` click handler. Maybe its just a typo from transferring the code to SO.

Comment: @showdev Ya i see that but there is still the `$(this).submit();` in `$('form').each` inside ajax success callback. OP should just put all relevant `input` to submit inside one FORM before submitting it

Comment: @showdev you're right. I missed that. Thank you.

Comment: @A.Wolff Agreed. You're right. I also agree with you that there's probably a more efficient way of doing this. Maybe [submit one form to two locations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279261/how-to-make-multiple-submit-action-on-a-single-submit-form#answer-18279328).